# OpenLayers3 GeoJSON with CRS throws error

Tags: openlayers-3, proj4js

I have a geoJSON resource as follows:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [...]
}
```

When I try to create the layer using:

```
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector( { 
    source: new ol.source.Vector( {
        url: "http://some.closed.api/resource.json",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    } )
} );
```

I get the following error and the GeoJSON isn't loaded into the map:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: transform should be defined
```

I downloaded the file locally and put on my web server and remove the "crs" or replace it with "EPSG:4326" it works as expected.

Can someone suggest a solution that doesn't require hardcoding a CRS into my olSource constructor?

Comment: Are you using some custom OL build?

Comment: No, I am not using a custom build. Maybe is has something to do with a relative url (i.e. data/resource.json) to the GeoJSON?

Comment: It has to do with the way CRS name is declared within your geojson. Try to set `crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
         "name": "EPSG:4326"
      }
   },` within your geojson.

Comment: I don't have control over the JSON in production so that won't work. Is there any reason why projections via OGC CRS URNs such as: "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" don't work? Is there some configuration that I can do to support these projection strings?

Comment: It indicates in the docs (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.proj.Projection.html) that these strings are supported...

Comment: I am afraid you have to dig into ol3 code `ol.format.geojson` and do some changes over there. Though, in terms of logic  `"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" ` is not a name. Instead it is the definition of your EPSG and not the name of it

Comment: I guess technically it's an alias. A definition would be "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs ".

Comment: true this is the alias name. should be accepted from ol3 as epsg:4326. I just dig a bit within ol3 code and seems to pass it as an alias. Just out of curiosity just before calling the layer initialiasation add this line of code `ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections(ol.proj.EPSG4326.PROJECTIONS);`

Comment: I added `ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections(ol.proj.EPSG4326.PROJECTIONS);` just before the layer initialization and I still get the error.

Comment: If i change the CRS to `"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS:84" } }` it works as expected. Note the colon between CRS and 84. I believe that this is a bug in OpenLayers 3.